# Delete Embed Upon Certain Reaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to have an embed get deleted once a user reacts

```js
//msg = embed

message.channel.send(msg).then(msg => {

  msg.react('')
  msg.react('')
  msg.react('')

  const trashFilter = reaction => {
    return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
  }

  msg.awaitReactions(trashFilter, { max: 1, time: 2592000, errors: ['time'] }).then((collected, msg) => {

    const reaction = collected

    if (reaction === '') {
      msg.delete({ timeout: 100 })
    }

  })


})
```

This does not successfully delete the message. Any better methods to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not successfully delete the message"?

Comment: The message is not deleted, Nor does the block yield error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the `msg` parameter you passed within `awaitReactions()`'s `then()` since `msg.delete()` does not refer to the original `msg` and also `awaitReactions()` does not return a message, just a collection of `messageReactions` so you only need to pass `collected`

```js
message.channel.send(msg).then(msg => {

  msg.react('')
  msg.react('')
  msg.react('')

  const trashFilter = reaction => {
    return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
  }

  msg.awaitReactions(trashFilter, { max: 1, time: 2592000, errors: ['time'] }).then((collected) => {

    const reaction = collected

    if (reaction === '') {
      msg.delete({ timeout: 100 })
    }

  })
})
```